# Find data between a range of dates

Tags: sql, date, mariadb

I want to find data with the same sum within 2 days before and 2 days after a specific date. The query below is fetching data from 2017-09-02. I know that `<>` means before and after the specific date.

```
SELECT id, datetime_payed, COUNT(data_sum) AS existing
FROM transactions
WHERE id_user = '1'
AND data_sum = '-149.00'
AND DATE(datetime_payed) <> '2018-03-02'
```

I want it to look for any data with the same sum between for 2018-02-28 and 2018-03-04, if the specific date is 2018-03-02, like in the query above.

How can I accomplish this?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not exactly.  `<>` means "not equals".  Many languages use `!=` for this (which is supported by many databases).

The logic you want is more like this:

```
SELECT SUM(data_sum) AS existing
FROM transactions
WHERE id_user = 1 AND
      data_sum = -149.00 AND
      datetime_payed >= DATE('2018-03-02') - interval 2 day AND
      datetime_payed <= DATE('2018-03-02') + interval 2 day ;
```

Notes:

- I removed the extraneous columns from the `SELECT`.  If you want more information, either use an aggregation function or `GROUP BY`.
- Numeric constants should not use single quotes.  I assume `id_user` and `data_sum` are numbers.
- The context of the question suggests that you want `SUM()` rather than `COUNT()`.
- The interval expressions might not be exactly what you want.  Your phrasing of the interval is ambiguous as I read the question.

Comment: Ah! Thank you for the correction of `<>` :) And very much thank you for a good solution! I'll accept it when I can.

Comment: Wrapping `DATE()` around the literal is unnecessary in this context.